# What are ConduitEventConsumer-pool-9687-thread-2 in Platform Event Debug Logs

Tags: platform-event, debug-logs

This is the first time I saw something like this. We fire Platform Events from many places, and they are in plenty, you can say around 100 in a minute in worst case scenario.

Is there any kind of limit for using Platform Events which are causing these issues ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to provide examples of these logs? What exactly is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: @Somya did you get an answer to the underlying cause in your case?  I'm seeing the ConduitEventConsumer transactions when updating a contact from a platform event.  In my case it was the DuplicateDetector.